# PDF Button That Links To Website

Tags: html, pdf, button, hyperlink

Does anyone know how (or if it is even possible) to create a button on an html page that, when that webpage is saved as a PDF, the button is still functional? I am trying to have this button link to a webpage so that in the PDF, the user can click on the button to go to a link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of options:

1. Use the `<a/>` tag and style it as a link.
2. If your PDF conversion engine supports javascript, then you could provide `onclick` behavior.

I would go with #1. Also, if you are looking for a PDF conversion tool that support javascript you could either use [WKHTMLTOPDF](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) or use the API based HTML to PDF conversion tool [Sprint PDF](http://www.sprintpdf.com).